# Slider refuses to center photos, forces left justified

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, width

This is a really great slider but it has just one annoying fault. If I have different widths of images, the ones that are too small for the default width, are left justified. I've tried every which way to do it with the html/css but it's somewhere in the js I think. I even loaded the js after the images load and it still put it left justified even though they were centered for that split second before the js loaded. What seems to happen is, the js takes the smaller width image and makes it the full default width and adds whitespace to the right of it, essentially making it a full width image. I am just curious if this is customizable so that the photo is centered and whitespace is added on either side.

Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks for taking a look.

```
(function ($) {
    var params = new Array;
    var order = new Array;
    var images = new Array;
    var links = new Array;
    var linksTarget = new Array;
    var titles = new Array;
    var interval = new Array;
    var imagePos = new Array;
    var appInterval = new Array;
    var squarePos = new Array;
    var reverse = new Array;
    $.fn.coinslider = $.fn.CoinSlider = function (options) {
        init = function (el) {
            order[el.id] = new Array();
            images[el.id] = new Array();
            links[el.id] = new Array();
            linksTarget[el.id] = new Array();
            titles[el.id] = new Array();
            imagePos[el.id] = 0;
            squarePos[el.id] = 0;
            reverse[el.id] = 1;
            params[el.id] = $.extend({}, $.fn.coinslider.defaults, options);
            $.each($('#' + el.id + ' img'), function (i, item) {
                images[el.id][i] = $(item).attr('src');
                links[el.id][i] = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('href') : '';
                linksTarget[el.id][i] = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('target') : '';
                titles[el.id][i] = $(item).next().is('span') ? $(item).next().html() : '';
                $(item).hide();
                $(item).next().hide();
            });
            $(el).css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + images[el.id][0] + ')',
                'width': params[el.id].width,
                'height': params[el.id].height,
                'position': 'relative',
                'background-position': 'top left'
            }).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-" + el.id + "' />");
            $('#' + el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-" + el.id + "' style='position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");
            $.setFields(el);
            if (params[el.id].navigation) $.setNavigation(el);
            $.transition(el, 0);
            $.transitionCall(el);
        }
        $.setFields = function (el) {
            tWidth = sWidth = parseInt(params[el.id].width / params[el.id].spw);
            tHeight = sHeight = parseInt(params[el.id].height / params[el.id].sph);
            counter = sLeft = sTop = 0;
            tgapx = gapx = params[el.id].width - params[el.id].spw * sWidth;
            tgapy = gapy = params[el.id].height - params[el.id].sph * sHeight;
            for (i = 1; i <= params[el.id].sph; i++) {
                gapx = tgapx;
                if (gapy > 0) {
                    gapy--;
                    sHeight = tHeight + 1;
                } else {
                    sHeight = tHeight;
                }
                for (j = 1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++) {
                    if (gapx > 0) {
                        gapx--;
                        sWidth = tWidth + 1;
                    } else {
                        sWidth = tWidth;
                    }
                    order[el.id][counter] = i + '' + j;
                    counter++;
                    if (params[el.id].links) $('#' + el.id).append("<a href='" + links[el.id][0] + "' class='cs-" + el.id + "' id='cs-" + el.id + i + j + "' style='width:" + sWidth + "px; height:" + sHeight + "px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");
                    else $('#' + el.id).append("<div class='cs-" + el.id + "' id='cs-" + el.id + i + j + "' style='width:" + sWidth + "px; height:" + sHeight + "px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");
                    $("#cs-" + el.id + i + j).css({
                        'background-position': -sLeft + 'px ' + (-sTop + 'px'),
                        'left': sLeft,
                        'top': sTop
                    });
                    sLeft += sWidth;
                }
                sTop += sHeight;
                sLeft = 0;
            }
            $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show();
            });
            $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
            });
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show();
            });
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
            });
            if (params[el.id].hoverPause) {
                $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
                    params[el.id].pause = true;
                });
                $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
                    params[el.id].pause = false;
                });
                $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
                    params[el.id].pause = true;
                });
                $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
                    params[el.id].pause = false;
                });
            }
        };
        $.transitionCall = function (el) {
            clearInterval(interval[el.id]);
            delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw * params[el.id].sph * params[el.id].sDelay;
            interval[el.id] = setInterval(function () {
                $.transition(el)
            }, delay);
        }
        $.transition = function (el, direction) {
            if (params[el.id].pause == true) return;
            $.effect(el);
            squarePos[el.id] = 0;
            appInterval[el.id] = setInterval(function () {
                $.appereance(el, order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])
            }, params[el.id].sDelay);
            $(el).css({
                'background-image': 'url(' + images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]] + ')'
            });
            if (typeof (direction) == "undefined") imagePos[el.id]++;
            else if (direction == 'prev') imagePos[el.id]--;
            else imagePos[el.id] = direction;
            if (imagePos[el.id] == images[el.id].length) {
                imagePos[el.id] = 0;
            }
            if (imagePos[el.id] == -1) {
                imagePos[el.id] = images[el.id].length - 1;
            }
            $('.cs-button-' + el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
            $('#cs-button-' + el.id + "-" + (imagePos[el.id] + 1)).addClass('cs-active');
            if (titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]) {
                $('#cs-title-' + el.id).css({
                    'opacity': 0
                }).animate({
                    'opacity': params[el.id].opacity
                }, params[el.id].titleSpeed);
                $('#cs-title-' + el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
            } else {
                $('#cs-title-' + el.id).css('opacity', 0);
            }
        };
        $.appereance = function (el, sid) {
            $('.cs-' + el.id).attr('href', links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target', linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
            if (squarePos[el.id] == params[el.id].spw * params[el.id].sph) {
                clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);
                return;
            }
            $('#cs-' + el.id + sid).css({
                opacity: 0,
                'background-image': 'url(' + images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]] + ')',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                'background-color': '#fff',
            });
            $('#cs-' + el.id + sid).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 300);
            squarePos[el.id]++;
        };
        $.setNavigation = function (el) {
            $(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-" + el.id + "'></div>");
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-" + el.id + "' class='cs-prev'></a>");
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-" + el.id + "' class='cs-next'></a>");
            $('#cs-prev-' + el.id).css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': 0,
                'left': 0,
                'z-index': 1001,
                'line-height': '30px',
                'opacity': params[el.id].opacity
            }).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el, 'prev');
                $.transitionCall(el);
            }).mouseover(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show()
            });
            $('#cs-next-' + el.id).css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': 0,
                'right': 0,
                'z-index': 1001,
                'line-height': '30px',
                'opacity': params[el.id].opacity
            }).click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el);
                $.transitionCall(el);
            }).mouseover(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show()
            });
            $("<div id='cs-buttons-" + el.id + "' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-' + el.id));
            for (k = 1; k < images[el.id].length + 1; k++) {
                $('#cs-buttons-' + el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-" + el.id + "' id='cs-button-" + el.id + "-" + k + "'>" + k + "</a>");
            }
            $.each($('.cs-button-' + el.id), function (i, item) {
                $(item).click(function (e) {
                    $('.cs-button-' + el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
                    $(this).addClass('cs-active');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.transition(el, i);
                    $.transitionCall(el);
                })
            });
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id + ' a').mouseout(function () {
                $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            });
            $("#cs-buttons-" + el.id) /*.css({'right':'50%','margin-left':-images[el.id].length*15/2-5,'position':'relative'})*/
            ;
        }
        $.effect = function (el) {
            effA = ['random', 'swirl', 'rain', 'straight'];
            if (params[el.id].effect == '') eff = effA[Math.floor(Math.random() * (effA.length))];
            else eff = params[el.id].effect;
            order[el.id] = new Array();
            if (eff == 'random') {
                counter = 0;
                for (i = 1; i <= params[el.id].sph; i++) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++) {
                        order[el.id][counter] = i + '' + j;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
                $.random(order[el.id]);
            }
            if (eff == 'rain') {
                $.rain(el);
            }
            if (eff == 'swirl') $.swirl(el);
            if (eff == 'straight') $.straight(el);
            reverse[el.id] *= -1;
            if (reverse[el.id] > 0) {
                order[el.id].reverse();
            }
        }
        $.random = function (arr) {
            var i = arr.length;
            if (i == 0) return false;
            while (--i) {
                var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                var tempi = arr[i];
                var tempj = arr[j];
                arr[i] = tempj;
                arr[j] = tempi;
            }
        }
        $.swirl = function (el) {
            var n = params[el.id].sph;
            var m = params[el.id].spw;
            var x = 1;
            var y = 1;
            var going = 0;
            var num = 0;
            var c = 0;
            var dowhile = true;
            while (dowhile) {
                num = (going == 0 || going == 2) ? m : n;
                for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                    order[el.id][c] = x + '' + y;
                    c++;
                    if (i != num) {
                        switch (going) {
                        case 0:
                            y++;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            x++;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            y--;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            x--;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                going = (going + 1) % 4;
                switch (going) {
                case 0:
                    m--;
                    y++;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    n--;
                    x++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    m--;
                    y--;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    n--;
                    x--;
                    break;
                }
                check = $.max(n, m) - $.min(n, m);
                if (m <= check && n <= check) dowhile = false;
            }
        }
        $.rain = function (el) {
            var n = params[el.id].sph;
            var m = params[el.id].spw;
            var c = 0;
            var to = to2 = from = 1;
            var dowhile = true;
            while (dowhile) {
                for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
                    order[el.id][c] = i + '' + parseInt(to2 - i + 1);
                    c++;
                }
                to2++;
                if (to < n && to2 < m && n < m) {
                    to++;
                }
                if (to < n && n >= m) {
                    to++;
                }
                if (to2 > m) {
                    from++;
                }
                if (from > to) dowhile = false;
            }
        }
        $.straight = function (el) {
            counter = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= params[el.id].sph; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++) {
                    order[el.id][counter] = i + '' + j;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        $.min = function (n, m) {
            if (n > m) return m;
            else return n;
        }
        $.max = function (n, m) {
            if (n < m) return m;
            else return n;
        }
        this.each(function () {
            init(this);
        });
    };
    $.fn.coinslider.defaults = {
        width: 828,
        height: 200,
        spw: 1,
        sph: 1,
        delay: 4000,
        sDelay: 30,
        opacity: 0.7,
        titleSpeed: 500,
        effect: '',
        navigation: true,
        links: false,
        hoverPause: true
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be taking the image source url and putting it into the background of the slider. I would first try changing

```
'background-position': 'top left'
```

to:

```
'background-position': 'center center'
```

... actually, the entire script seems geared towards tiling the images. I'd imagine that's the technique it uses to generate some of its cool effects. This line is where it's centering the current image within the tile defined by sph and spw.

```
'background-position': -sLeft + 'px ' + (-sTop + 'px'),
```

and if you use spw=1 and sph=1 you can center it by changing that to a fixed 'center center'.

I don't really care for this script in terms of general purpose, but it seems to have worked well for the person who wrote it.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I am pretty sure I tried this already. -- That didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

this is my hacky solution

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
            $('#coin-slider').coinslider({
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    effect: "rain",
                    hoverPause: true,
                    dely: 3000
            });

            // center coin slider
            setTimeout(function(){
                centerCS();
            },500);


    });     

    // center coin slider image
    function centerCS(){
        var w=$(".container").width();  // container of coin slider
        var csw=$("#coin-slider").width();
        var lpad=(w-csw)/2;

        $("#coin-slider").css("margin-left",lpad+"px");

    }

</script>
```